# Здравствуйте, хочу сделать чтоб при нажатии на кнопку переходил на новый url и выводило в окно блога новые данные из нового url, а не старые данные

Tags: javascript

```
  <script defer>
  let url = "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/posts?page=1";
  let p;
  document.getElementById("btnF").addEventListener("click", function () {
    url = "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/posts?page=2";
    Removez();
    Load();
  });

  let data;
  let arr2 = []; // список оглавлений
  console.log(arr2);

  function Removez() {
    let v = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    console.log(v);
    while (v.length > 0) v[0].remove();
  }

  async function Load() {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    console.log(response.url);
    data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    let TotalPagesValue = data["meta"]["pagination"]["pages"]; //общее страниц количество
    let TotalPageValue = data["meta"]["pagination"]["page"]; //общее статей количество
    console.log(TotalPagesValue);
    console.log(TotalPageValue);

    let KeysOfHeader = data["data"];

    let parent = document.getElementById("parent");

    for (let key in KeysOfHeader) {
      let AllHeaders = KeysOfHeader[key]["title"];
      console.log(AllHeaders);
      arr2.push(AllHeaders);
    }

    let x = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= arr2.length; i++) {
      p = document.createElement("p");
      p.className = "par";
      p.textContent = arr2[x];
      x = x + 1;
      parent.appendChild(p);
    }
  }
  Load();
</script>
```

Comment: Во-первых, не нужно весь вопрос писать в заголовке. Во-вторых, каким образом Вы пытаетесь выполнить свой код на другой/чужой странице? Либо Вы не сформулировали вопрос, либо пытаетесь сделать то, что невозможно.

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку "btnF" меняется url далее  срабатывает функция  Removez() которая удаляет построенный элементы в дом-дереве (по предыдущей ссылке). Затем запускается функция  Load() которая получив новый url и новые данные по нему строит новое дерево элементов. Так вот, на данный момент работает это странно, Removez()  удаляет элементы, построенные по первой ссылке, но когда срабатывает Load() они вновь появляются вначале страницы, а новые элементы строятся уже под ними. Хочется чтоб  при удалении они исчезали навсегда и не проявлялись,.

Comment: Во-первых, глобальные переменные - зло. При необходимости лучше вызвать метод и передать ему нужные данные параметром/объектом. Гадаю/"вангую", что Вам нужно не переходить по новой ссылке, а получить с неё json данные и актуализировать текущий контент страницы. Если так, то лучше использовать какой-нибудь фреймворк для привязки данных, коих множество. Хоть [vue.js](https://vuejs.org). Скорее всего Вам нужны [шаблоны](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html), а данные обрабатывать в [цикле](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for).